# How to test  a logistic regression model developed on a training sample on the data left out using R?

Tags: r, regression, logistic, cross-validation

I have the summary of a logistic regression output in R.  I used training data to make the model.

- How do I test the logistic regression model developed on the training data on the data left out?

My naive guess is to create a function then run each test same through that (not even sure how do pull that) but I have to imagine there's a better way.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `predict()` for that. You need the model fitted to the training data, and the data from your test group. With `type="response"`, you'll get the predicted probabilities, the default is the predicted logits.

```
# generate some data for a logistic regression, all observations
x    <- rnorm(100, 175, 7)                     # predictor variable
y    <- 0.4*x + 10 + rnorm(100, 0, 3)          # continuous predicted variable
yFac <- cut(y, breaks=c(-Inf, median(y), Inf), labels=c("lo", "hi"))    # median split
d    <- data.frame(yFac, x)                    # data frame

# now set aside training sample and corresponding test sample
idxTrn <- 1:70                                 # training sample
idxTst <- !(1:nrow(d) %in% idxTrn)             # test sample -> all remaining obs
# if idxTrn were a logical index vector, this would just be idxTst <- !idxTrn

# fit logistic regression only to training sample
fitTrn <- glm(yFac ~ x, family=binomial(link="logit"), data=d, subset=idxTrn)

# apply fitted model to test sample (predicted probabilities)
predTst <- predict(fitTrn, d[idxTst, ], type="response")
```

Now you may compare the predicted probabilities against actuall class values however you like. You may set a threshold for categorizing the predicted probabilities, and compare actual against predicted category memberships.

```
> thresh  <- 0.5            # threshold for categorizing predicted probabilities
> predFac <- cut(predTst, breaks=c(-Inf, thresh, Inf), labels=c("lo", "hi"))
> cTab    <- table(yFac[idxTst], predFac, dnn=c("actual", "predicted"))
> addmargins(cTab)
      predicted
actual lo hi Sum
   lo  12  4  16
   hi   5  9  14
   Sum 17 13  30
```

Note that the dataframe supplied to `predict()` needs to have the same variable names as the df used in the call to `glm()`, and the factors need to have the same levels in the same order. If you're interested in k-fold cross validation, have a look at the `cv.glm()` function from package `boot`.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to take a close look at the [caret](http://cran.r-project.org/package=caret) package which has a *lot* of support for this type of analysis.  Its four vignettes give a good overview of how it can help you with this.